# Create trigger in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, database-trigger

I have two tables A and B. A has the following columns :
`a_name, a_num, a_addr`. B also has these columns.

Whenever I insert a record in A, I want that record to be inserted in B as well by the use of a trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
begin
if tg_op='INSERT' then
insert into b values (new.a_name ,new.a_num ,new.a_addr);
return new;
end if;
return null;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;

---------------------------
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_a
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON a
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger();
```

Comment: Hi Anand. Thank your very much for your response. It makes total sense now. But, i get an error when creating the trigger function as here

`ERROR: syntax error at or near "begin"
LINE 10: begin`

Comment: i have edited answer again .kindly go through again.

Comment: Great. it's working.. But, there's another slight mistake in your insert query, which is to separate values by comma. Thanks @Anand